# How to add extended elements in polymer by createElement()

Tags: javascript, polymer

```
 var elm = document.createElement("tr");                
 this.$.myLovelyContainer.appendChild(elm);
```

I need to add a `<tr is="custom-tag"...>` node in myLovelyContainer.

Thx for help guys :)

--- more info I just saw

The problem is when I add this via `document.createelement` , it creates but does not create the content of it. This is an extended tr element that has td tags in it.

It just adds the tag in page but it is always invisible. And the custom-element fucntions does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (for a table with id = myLovelyContainer):

```
var elm = document.createElement("tr");
var a = document.createAttribute( "is" );
a.value = "custom-tag";
elm.setAttributeNode(a);
var elm2 = document.createElement("td");
var content = document.createTextNode( "Hello world!" ); 
elm2.appendChild( content );
elm.appendChild( elm2 );
var myLovelyContainer = document.getElementById( 'myLovelyContainer' );
myLovelyContainer.appendChild(elm);
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tbdycybm/

Comment: Thx for the answer. But what I am actually looking for was a default behaviour that renders its content. The custom-element already defines td tags in it.

Found the solution :) Thx again

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#type-extension) is the solution

```
var elm = document.createElement("tr","custom-tag");
```

I needed mor research but now I am happy :) By this creation way it just acts normal, creates its content and initializez all properties and methods.

I wish polymer has much more detailed tutorials.